# Manipulating DocList in SOLR

Tags: solr, solrj

I have written a custom request handler in solr to meet my business requirements. The handler involves getting data from two different from SolrIndexSearchers. I want the returned doclists from the two SolrIndexSearchers merged into one.

I tried iterating through one and adding doc by doc to another, but all I could get was an "Unsupported Operation" exception. Is there anyway to merge two doclists?

[Edit 1] : Code snippet inside the overridden handleRequestBody method

```
   SolrCore core = new SolrCore("Desired Directory 1", schema);
   reader = IndexReader.open("Desired Directory 1");
   searcher = new SolrIndexSearcher(core, schema, getName(), reader, false);
   Sort lsort = null;
   FilteredQuery filter = null;
   DocList results1 = searcher.getDocList(query, filter, lsort, 0, 10);
   reader.close();
   searcher.close();
   core.close();
   SolrCore core = new SolrCore("Desired Directory 2", schema);
   reader = IndexReader.open("Desired Directory 2");
   searcher = new SolrIndexSearcher(core, schema, getName(), reader, false);
   Sort lsort = null;
   FilteredQuery filter = null;
   DocList results2 = searcher.getDocList(query, filter, lsort, 0, 10);
   reader.close();
   searcher.close();
   core.close();
   rsp.add("response",results1);
   rsp.add("response",results2);
```

Now that I have two DocLists results1 and results2, how do I merge them?

[Edit 2] : The problem is not an exception/stack trace. When I add two responses, I get the results in two response sets when it is a single machine search. When it is a distributed search, I only get the distribution between response 1 of machine 1 and response 1 of machine 2. IN my understanding, only when I merge the responses to a single set, I will be able to get proper distribution. Hope I am understandable?

Comment: Can you please add to your question the code you're using?

Comment: Done @Javanna So what's your take?

Comment: Not sure, can you please add your stacktrace too?

Comment: Hope the edit helps you @javanna

Comment: If those two queries & filters are identical: have you tried to search across multiple cores like this: localhost/solr/core0/select?shards=localhost/solr/core0,localhost/solr/core1&q=test<br> Why are you writing your own requestHandler at the first place?

Comment: @mbonaci of course I tried. I wrote my own request handler because, I will have to dynamically fire cores based on an incoming request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocList is not supposed to be changed after you retrieve it from a search result.

I had the similar problem and, if I remember correctly, I used:

```
org.apache.solr.util.SolrPluginUtils.docListToSolrDocumentList
```

to convert `DocList` to `SolrDocumentList`, which extends `ArrayList<SolrDocument>`, which consequently supports `add(SolrDocument)`.

So the worst case scenario (from the performance standpoint) is to convert the first `DocList` to `SolrDocumentList` and then loop through all other `DocLists` calling `add` on each doc. 
You'll have to test how efficient this approach is. I'm not Solr expert, but this is where I'd start testing.